# How to start xorg on a physically connected display via SSH?

Tags: ssh, hdmi, display, xorg

The pi is configured to start into text mode so that no xorg libraries are loaded during normal operation. Yet I would like to be able to occasionally run an xorg desktop session when connected to an HDMI display.

I already have enabled HDMI display with:

```
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

The HDMI screen is working in text mode. I have no keyboard connected to the pi and therefore would like to control it via ssh which is already working.

I tried starting the xorg session via ssh with `startx -- -layout HDMI` but this did not work for obvious reasons, since xorg is not gonna run through a ssh connection.

So the question is how to start xorg on the physical HDMI display via an ssh connection?

Running e.g.

```
startx -- vt7
```

results in the following error:

```
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 7 (Permission denied)
```

Using `export DISPLAY=:0.0` did not make any difference.

I am currently using the workaround of changing the boot type using `sudo raspi-config` > Boot Options > Desktop GUI but would like to be able to start xorg on-demand via an ssh session.

Comment: what happens if you run `startx` when you're logged in with ssh?

Comment: it fails with an error message

Comment: `an error message` What error message?

Comment: added error message to the question

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have no keyboard, I assume you want to run X for some specific program, other than a login screen.  Specify that program as an argument to `xinit`, for example run `xinit /usr/bin/chromium`.

Comment: I want to run the full-blown desktop and use some kind of virtual onscreen keyboard which I can operate with a USB mouse. The temporary workaround I'm using is running `raspi-config` and enabling passwordless xorg autostart but that loads xorg unconditionally on every boot..

Comment: in fact, found a working onscreen keyboard: `apt-get install matchbox-keyboard`

Comment: Can you xinit your window manager?

Comment: not when I am connected via ssh

Comment: Can you please provide details of the command and the corresponding error message?

Comment: added the command and error message to the question